# Chrome extension authenticate user via your website

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, authentication, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a chrome extension and already have a website running. I want to authenticate my extension using my website on which the user is already authenticated.

Now, my understanding is, I can exchange information betwen my website and my extension using window.postMessage and window.addEventListener, but what is unclear to me is the following:

**How do I check if the message was infact send from my extension and is not a forged request?**

Answer (score 0):

I would invoke the chrome extension to open a unique URL which is generated to authenticate the user.

This is the same concept as the password reset by email with only a link

Also make sure that the URL has an expiry date something like 2 minutes.

Comment: The problem with this approach that I see, is that If i understand it correctly, my extension would have to request that url from the server (axios.get('example.com/get-unique-url')) and anyone could forge that request to get that authentication token on behave of the user. The idea of extension being authenticated by a website would require the extension to have means of authenticating itself via some unique token or something like this, which I'm not sure is possible the more I read about it.